# Semiprime Factorization - Length against Time

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization, semiprimes

I'm looking for current information on how long it takes to factor semiprimes of a given length.  MIPS against bit length or decimal length of N using best known algorithm would be ideal but any suitable analogue would also be appreciated.

I've found plenty of information on progress on factorization (digits against years)
https://aiimpacts.org/progress-in-general-purpose-factoring/

The only information relevant to my concern that I've found either has too theoretical
https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=jas.2006.458.481

See figure 2 here (the Y axis has too great a step)
http://docsdrive.com/images/ansinet/jas/2006/fig2-2k6-458-481.gif

or too limited
See various graphs of numerical methods and SAT solvers here (they stop at between 50 and 100 binary digits. also, the y-scale is not ideal)
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.01448.pdf

I'm looking at understanding how long it would take (in MIPS) to factor a semiprime up to length of perhaps 300 binary digits, give or take.

Is this simply understanding the complexity of an algorithm and multiplying it times a constant to arrive at the MIPS?

Comment: I'm sure the timings that apply to general purpose factorization also apply to semiprimes (by which I take it you mean products of two distinct primes).

Comment: That's correct.  And while I can find information on complexity for GNFS on Wikipedia I'm having trouble translating this to how long it should take to factor an n-bit semiprime.  I can find instances say of a particular program (YAFU) quoted for factoring a 300 bit semiprime on a 1.8 GHz machine (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).  I also find a reference to 8000 MIPS years to break RSA-155(512 bits).  But I'm at a loss at generating an expected curve for n between 0 and 512 bits tying bit length to MIPS.

Comment: I think you mean fastest timing. you can in theory use the sieve of sundaram twice on ordered pairs and find all semiprimes in a range.

Comment: odd semiprimes ( including squares) rather.